# Data loss from Excel upload to Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have an excel file which has 3 tabs. 
2 of the tabs are loaded with revenue data correctly, however there is one tab which is getting partially loaded. 
Count of rows in the excel is 96,652 whereas after uploading in power BI it is 49,999. 
Not sure why there is data loss?

As a workaround, I copied and pasted excel data as values in another excel file to test it. And, it is working fine and there is no data loss. 
Not sure, why Power BI is reading partial data through excel for that particular tab.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue is due to maximum allowed data. Can you try to change below option and reload same file?

Open your report in Power BI Desktop editor and go to Menu **File ->  Options and Settings -> Options** 
Under **Global** section, increase **Maximum allowed (MB)** size  to some higher number and try to load your file again.